# amd-dependency is deprecated. How to use import "module"

Tags: javascript, typescript, amd

Our web application (TypeScript 2.1.4) targets amd module and uses `///<amd-dependency />` to load template with requirejs.
Today we are using with success the following syntax to load an html string into the tpl variable :

```
/// <amd-dependency path="text!tpl/components/header/header.view.html" name="tpl"/>
declare var tpl: string;
```

Henceforth [this directive is deprecated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) :

> /// < amd-dependency />
>
> this directive has been deprecated. Use import "moduleName";
>   statements instead.

To replace the triple slash directive we used a wild card module in a local.d.ts file :

```
declare module "text!*" {
    var _: string;
    export default _;
}
```

and replaced the directive with :

```
import tpl from "text!tpl/components/header/header.view.html";
```

The compilation with tsc is fine but the loading of the template fails.
Looking a the js, the compilation produces :

`define([text!tpl/components/header/header.view.html, ...],function(header_view_html_1, ...) method` 
as expected but then uses header_view_html_1.**default** in the module.

Debugging the js file, the template is in the `header_view_html_1` variable not in the `header_view_html_1.**default**` property which is undefined.

Why typescript produces this default property ? How to avoid it and keep header_view_html_1 ?

**Edit** : I followed guidances from typescriptlang modules [Wildcard module declarations](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#wildcard-module-declarations)

```
declare module "json!*" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
import data from "json!http://example.com/data.json";
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to adjust your import statement...

This imports everything into the alias from the module.

```
import * as yourAlias from "..."
```

This imports specific parts and makes them available directly.

```
import {thing, anotherThing} from "..."
```

Comment: I already tried `import * as tpl from "text!tpl/components/header/header.view.html";` but it throws a compilation error : error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof "text!*"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Answer (score 0):

Since we're migrating the build system to webpack2, I end up using `html-loader`:

```
module: {
   rules: [
      {
         test: /\.html$/,
         use: "html-loader"
      }
```

and load the template with :

```
let tpl = require("./header.view.html");
```